# Word VBA to return the height and width of a preselected image

Tags: vba

I have a Word macro that changes the orientation and page size of an individual page to accommodate the image placed on the selected page. My existing macro code does the page and footer resizing correctly (footers are based on our existing footer styles), but I'd like to enhance the code to display the height and width of the selected image before the userform appears to help guide the user's page size choice.

The user could get that information by right-clicking the image, choosing "Picture...", and selecting the "Size" tab in the "Format Object" window, but I am trying to have the height/width displayed as part of the macro instead of asking the user to follow those steps.

Editors in my department sometimes encounter documents in which an image has been placed on a page that is not wide enough to accommodate the entire image, resulting in part of the image being "cut off." My plan has been to have the user select the image on the Word page, then run the macro; the image's height and width (in inches, ideally) should be displayed prior to the user to selecting the optimal page size.

I've tried working with Selection.ShapeRange or Selection.InlineShapes, but I haven't yet been able to get the current height and width of the selected image. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
KRS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I opted to handle this:

My macro was designed to start with the user selecting an inline shape on the Word page. With that selection, I start by setting variables for the selection's width and height in points, convert to inches, and display the results in a MsgBox:

```
    myHeightPoints = .Height
    myWidthPoints = .Width

    `Convert the previously established variable to inches`
    `Dim myHeightInches As Double
    Dim myWidthInches As Double
    myHeightInches = myHeightPoints / Application.InchesToPoints(1)
    myWidthInches = myWidthPoints / Application.InchesToPoints(1)

    `Trim the result to 2 decimal places`
    Dim myHeightDisplay
    Dim myWidthDisplay
    myHeightDisplay = Format(myHeightInches, "#.00")
    myWidthDisplay = Format(myWidthInches, "#.00")

    `Display the result`
    MsgBox ("The selected image is " & myHeightDisplay & " H   X   " & myWidthDisplay
    & " W" & Chr(13) & "Choose a page size that accomodates the figure and its caption.")
```